# Comparing an Unknown Xeon Single Core processor with Core2Quad Q9650

Tags: dedicated-server

I was in the market for a cheap server and I got a deal for $30 on one with a Xeon single core processor but they did not tell me which model it is. At that time the specs weren't a big deal so I agreed to go with it. Something happened during the ordering process and they ended up getting two orders. One for the Xeon which I agreed to and another one with a Core2Quad 9650. I told them I ordered only one server and they cancelled the order with the Xeon.

I now have the Core2Quad Q9650. As the price is the same for both the servers, should I ask them to change it to the Xeon one or keep this one? I understand that Xeon is for enterprise and Core2Quad is for consumer desktops but does that really matter for a small website with very low traffic?

Given that the price is the same and assuming that both the servers are comparable in performance, is it fair to compare a single core Xeon with an unknown model number and a Core2Quad Q9650? Is it possible that my current one performs better than the agreed upon server? The rest of the specs are identical.

Comment: How can anyone answer this? What's the point of trying to compare to an "unknown Xeon"?

Comment: Also there has been no single core xeon for years, so your info is inaccurate or misunderstood at some point.

Comment: @JamesRyan He's talking about leasing a dedicated web server, so I suppose it's not out of the realm of possibility that he might be able to lease a server that's running one of the last single-core Xeons (which were released in 2007, IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

> is it fair to compare a single core Xeon with an unknown model number and a Core2Quad Q9650?

No, it's not.  They've been making Xeons forever, so only knowing that it's a Xeon is pretty useless.  Theoretically, it could be a Xeon from a decade ago, or more likely, it could be an architecture or two old, could be a low-performance, energy-efficient model, or whatever else.

Comment: From what I understand it, he rents the server and didn't buy it. I doubt you'll get any server, even an old used one, for $30.

Comment: @SvW Oh, yeah.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Guess I'll leave the top part, as it's still relevant.